# Company/User security handling in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have what I consider to be a pretty basic security issue for an application designed to be run as SaaS. The following image indicates the relation between entities:

[image]

Basically users of the company creates items which every other user of the company should have access to. The question is how to best solve this in Symfony2. Using ACL seems like overkill.

Also, most of the examples I've seen seem to handle the security measures in the controller action which seems strange to me. I would prefer the controller interact with a repository which handles the security and permissions internally.

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema shows the solution in my opinion.

The simplest coding scenario I could think of is:

```
My user is logged in
Get the user's company
Paginate all items attached to this company
```

You won't have an ACE system but that would do the work according to your question.

If you want an extra layer of flexibility I'd add `UserGroup` entity in the middle of `Company`, `User` and `Item`. `Item` would relate to `Company` through `UserGroup` and same thing for `User`.
This `UserGroup` entity could have an extra column that holds ACE data in a JSON-encoded string so that whenever you get the group you have directly access to the group's ACEs.

One thing I learned about ACL/ACE in general is that you will have to take the right amount of time to plan your integration otherwise it will become really hard to maintain.

To answer your last question, there isn't any best practices for ACLs. Symfony2 has a very generic ACL system that might not scale well however it will fit most requirements (if not all of them). I find Symfony2 ACL/ACE system great but the performance are far from great.

If you have the chance, you can wrap Symfony ACL/ACE system with a caching layer which would be ideal. However if your host doesn't allow you to install a solution such as Memcached or Redis then you can't use this solution.